# Помогите свернуть SideBar

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, itemtouchhelper

Нужно сделать чтоб SideBar при max-width 768px сворачивался так скажем в меню бутерброд. Но не понимаю как это сделать. Помогите пожалуйста)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

.graficlogo {
    padding: 5px;
    max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
    background: #F6C010;
    margin: 0;
}

#sidebar {
  border-right: 5px solid #F6C010;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  background: #151718;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#sidebar a {
  color: white;
}

main {
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#sidebar h3 {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li a {
  background: #1C1E1F;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background: #F6C010;
  transition: 0.25s;
  color: white;
}

footer {
    background: #F6C010;
    height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.social p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.footer_social_img {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.tovari_items {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 100px;
  padding: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tovari_items:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.tovar_list h3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#price h5 {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #F6C010;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.buy {
  outline: none;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: #68D81E;
  padding: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.buy:hover {
  background: #82F238;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>

            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title> MySite </title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        </head>

        <body>

            <header>
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="index.html"><img class="graficlogo" src="img/logo.png"></a>
                </div>
            </header>

            <div id="sidebar">
                <h3> Каталог товаров </h3> <a href="#"> &#9776; </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"> Телефоны и асскесуары </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Мужская одежда </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Женская одежда </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Детская одежда </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Бытовые приборы </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Уличные площадки </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Компьютерные акссесуары </a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>

            <main>

                    <div class="tovari_items">
                        <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/telefon.png">
                            <div class="tovar_list">
                                <h3> Huawei P30 Lite </h3>
                                    <div id="price">
                                        <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
                                        </div>              
                                    <div class="button">
                                <button class="buy" > Купить </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tovari_items">
                        <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/tovar_iphone11proMAX.png">
                            <div class="tovar_list">
                                <h3> Iphone 11 Pro Max </h3>
                                    <div id="price">
                                        <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
                                        </div>              
                                    <div class="button">
                                <button class="buy" > Купить </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tovari_items">
                        <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/telefon.png">
                            <div class="tovar_list">
                                <h3> Huawei P30 Lite </h3>
                                    <div id="price">
                                        <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
                                        </div>              
                                    <div class="button">
                                <button class="buy" > Купить </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tovari_items">
                        <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/tovar_iphone11proMAX.png">
                            <div class="tovar_list">
                                <h3> Iphone 11 Pro Max </h3>
                                    <div id="price">
                                        <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
                                        </div>              
                                    <div class="button">
                                <button class="buy" > Купить </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tovari_items">
                        <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/telefon.png">
                            <div class="tovar_list">
                                <h3> Huawei P30 Lite </h3>
                                    <div id="price">
                                        <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
                                        </div>              
                                    <div class="button">
                                <button class="buy" > Купить </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tovari_items">
                        <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/tovar_iphone11proMAX.png">
                            <div class="tovar_list">
                                <h3> Iphone 11 Pro Max </h3>
                                    <div id="price">
                                        <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
                                        </div>              
                                    <div class="button">
                                <button class="buy" > Купить </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tovari_items">
                        <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/telefon.png">
                            <div class="tovar_list">
                                <h3> Huawei P30 Lite </h3>
                                    <div id="price">
                                        <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
                                        </div>              
                                    <div class="button">
                                <button class="buy" > Купить </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tovari_items">
                        <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/tovar_iphone11proMAX.png">
                            <div class="tovar_list">
                                <h3> Iphone 11 Pro Max </h3>
                                    <div id="price">
                                        <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
                                        </div>              
                                    <div class="button">
                                <button class="buy" > Купить </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tovari_items">
                        <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/telefon.png">
                            <div class="tovar_list">
                                <h3> Huawei P30 Lite </h3>
                                    <div id="price">
                                        <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
                                        </div>              
                                    <div class="button">
                                <button class="buy" > Купить </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="tovari_items">
                        <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/tovar_iphone11proMAX.png">
                            <div class="tovar_list">
                                <h3> Iphone 11 Pro Max </h3>
                                    <div id="price">
                                        <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
                                        </div>              
                                    <div class="button">
                                <button class="buy" > Купить </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



            </main>

            <footer>
                <div class="social">
                    <p> Мы в социальных сетях! </p>
                        <div class="footer_social_img">
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/social_footer/footer_icon_instagram.png"></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/social_footer/footer_icon_facebook.png"></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/social_footer/footer_icon_twitter.png"></a>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </footer>

            <script src="js/script.js"></script>
        </body>

    </html>


menu.onclick = function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("sidebar");

  if (x.className === "sidebar") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "sidebar";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
var button = document.getElementById('sidebar__icon');
button.onclick = function() {
  sidebar.classList.toggle('sidebar__active');
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

.graficlogo {
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #F6C010;
  margin: 0;
}

#sidebar {
  border-right: 5px solid #F6C010;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  background: #151718;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#sidebar__icon {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #151718;
}

#sidebar__icon a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
}

.sidebar__active {
  display: block !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
  #sidebar__icon {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar {
    display: block;
  }
  #sidebar__icon {
    display: none;
  }
}

main {
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#sidebar h3 {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li a {
  background: #1C1E1F;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background: #F6C010;
  transition: 0.25s;
  color: white;
}

footer {
  background: #F6C010;
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.social p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.footer_social_img {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.tovari_items {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 100px;
  padding: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tovari_items:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.tovar_list h3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#price h5 {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #F6C010;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.buy {
  outline: none;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: #68D81E;
  padding: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.buy:hover {
  background: #82F238;
  transition: 0.25s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> MySite </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="index.html"><img class="graficlogo" src="img/logo.png"></a>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div id="sidebar">
    <h3> Каталог товаров </h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"> Телефоны и асскесуары </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Мужская одежда </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Женская одежда </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Детская одежда </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Бытовые приборы </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Уличные площадки </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Компьютерные акссесуары </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar__icon"><a href="#"> &#9776; </a></div>

  <main>

    <div class="tovari_items">
      <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/telefon.png">
        <div class="tovar_list">
          <h3> Huawei P30 Lite </h3>
          <div id="price">
            <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
          </div>
          <div class="button">
            <button class="buy"> Купить </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tovari_items">
      <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/tovar_iphone11proMAX.png">
        <div class="tovar_list">
          <h3> Iphone 11 Pro Max </h3>
          <div id="price">
            <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
          </div>
          <div class="button">
            <button class="buy"> Купить </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tovari_items">
      <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/telefon.png">
        <div class="tovar_list">
          <h3> Huawei P30 Lite </h3>
          <div id="price">
            <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
          </div>
          <div class="button">
            <button class="buy"> Купить </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tovari_items">
      <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/tovar_iphone11proMAX.png">
        <div class="tovar_list">
          <h3> Iphone 11 Pro Max </h3>
          <div id="price">
            <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
          </div>
          <div class="button">
            <button class="buy"> Купить </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tovari_items">
      <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/telefon.png">
        <div class="tovar_list">
          <h3> Huawei P30 Lite </h3>
          <div id="price">
            <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
          </div>
          <div class="button">
            <button class="buy"> Купить </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tovari_items">
      <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/tovar_iphone11proMAX.png">
        <div class="tovar_list">
          <h3> Iphone 11 Pro Max </h3>
          <div id="price">
            <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
          </div>
          <div class="button">
            <button class="buy"> Купить </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tovari_items">
      <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/telefon.png">
        <div class="tovar_list">
          <h3> Huawei P30 Lite </h3>
          <div id="price">
            <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
          </div>
          <div class="button">
            <button class="buy"> Купить </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tovari_items">
      <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/tovar_iphone11proMAX.png">
        <div class="tovar_list">
          <h3> Iphone 11 Pro Max </h3>
          <div id="price">
            <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
          </div>
          <div class="button">
            <button class="buy"> Купить </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tovari_items">
      <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/telefon.png">
        <div class="tovar_list">
          <h3> Huawei P30 Lite </h3>
          <div id="price">
            <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
          </div>
          <div class="button">
            <button class="buy"> Купить </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tovari_items">
      <div class="tovar_img"><img src="img\tovari_leaderpage/tovar_iphone11proMAX.png">
        <div class="tovar_list">
          <h3> Iphone 11 Pro Max </h3>
          <div id="price">
            <h5> 9999 грн. </h5>
          </div>
          <div class="button">
            <button class="buy"> Купить </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



  </main>

  <footer>
    <div class="social">
      <p> Мы в социальных сетях! </p>
      <div class="footer_social_img">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/social_footer/footer_icon_instagram.png"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/social_footer/footer_icon_facebook.png"></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/social_footer/footer_icon_twitter.png"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```